# What are eligibility criteria for Tenacious badge?

Tags: support, badges

I read about the Tenacious & Unsung Hero badges. I have 36 total answers, out of which 16 are accepted. Among these, 7 are with 0 votes.

As per the definition, I am eligible for the Tenacious badge, but I haven't been awarded it yet.

What are the hidden criteria?